# Booting from Puppy Linux USB cannot see sda1

Tags: devices, puppy-linux

I am booting from a Puppy Linux USB Flash drive so that I can tar the primary partition of the hard drive. I see sda2 through to sda15, sdb1 to 15 (sdb1 is USB boot disk), sdc1 to 15, sdd1 to 15, sde1 to 15, etc. But I do not see sda1.

When I boot normally (not with the flash drive), I do see sda1, as well as 2 & 5

Why am I not seeing sda1 when booting from flash drive?

Also would like to know why I am seeing a multitude of other sd_'s which are not there when booting normally.

Comment: _which_ puppy linux please.  //  device nodes in `/dev` can be created statically, for an anticipated number of partitions - this is how systems used to work before hotplug support.  compare `cat /proc/partitions` or `ls /sys/class/block` for the kernel's idea of what devices are really available.  i'm not sure why sda1 would be missed out from the pre-created device nodes though.  you could try `udevadm trigger` to get udev to rescan /sys, if that has the same problem of not creating sda1 then hopefully the problem will show as an error message in the system log.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try out what you've suggested. Cant remember off the top of my head what version of Puppy it was. I'll come back with that if necessary.

Comment: The hope is you can update this q/a, hopefully because you found a solution to your problem, then you should include the Puppy version because it will give people information about the scope of the error you hit.  e.g. if someone saw the same error in an earlier version, this might tell them that simply upgrading to your version might not help.

Comment: ["Who were you, DenverCoder9?  _What did you see?_"](https://xkcd.com/979/)

Comment: Version of Puppy Linux is 5.01

Comment: Sorry I took so long coming back to this. At the time I ended up building from scratch rather than cloning. But now I have come across the same issue again. Version of Puppy Linux is 5.01, 'cat /proc/partitions' shows what I would expect to see (sda1,2 & 5) and so does 'ls /sys/class/block'.. 'udevadm trigger' does not seem to make any difference although no errors, cant see anything that looks relevant in /var/log/messages.. The objective is to copy the hard disk to another unit

Comment: OK so the problem was that the boot stick is 32 bit and the unit is 64 bit.. I tried a 64 bit boot stick and all is ok

Comment: Cool. I knew this was going to be weird :). No apology expected, thanks for adding your new information. My best guess was the specific build of Puppy you had was buggy in some way, hence asking for the version :). It seems the 64-bit build you tried avoids it. I guess udev not creating device nodes might be explained by udev being written to expect them created by devtmpfs, but then it's so *weird* not to have devtmpfs mounted. One possibility is the 32-bit kernel was built without `CONFIG_DEVTMPFS_MOUNT` enabled. Puppy might have been less worried about saving RAM for the 64-bit kernel.

Comment: I.e. I bet if you have any 32-bit unit to run Puppy on, you would still not see `sda1` when using the "bad" boot stick :).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its amusing how seemingly weird/difficult issues have such simple solutions. I should have mentioned that the 64 bit boot stick has Debian on it.